# Truncated string in android spinners

Tags: android, spinner

On the iPhone, if an option is too long for the area, instead of wrappeing you get a "..." at the end of the "**drop down**" and the user will know there is more text than is shown.

I want to recreate this with android but am new to it so cant see how.

I want the heights of "**rows**" in my layout to be uniform hence not able to wrap the text.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Use a custom view for that, and specify by calling:

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.id.my_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Note that you have to use your own view here: my_simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In the layout you use for your `Spinner` rows, for the `TextView` containing the possibly-too-long text, use `android:ellipsize="end"`.

Answer (score 0):

In the layout you use for your Spinner rows, for the TextView containing the possibly-too-long text, use android:ellipsize="end".

I think you have to use the attribute singleLine

You are infact both right, you need to set the ellipsize and the single line attr.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to use the attribute [singleLine](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine), however, I don't know if it is possible with tableLayout or even advisable...
try it on a single texteview to see the effect, and then in your TL...